# Dealing with arbitrarily large inbound data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here's a function to remove specified characters from a string:

```js
function remove(str, chars) {
    var set = new Set(chars);
    return [...str].filter(i => !set.has(i)).join('');
}

console.log(remove('hello world', 'el') === 'ho word'); // true
```

But... what if the inbound string is arbitrarily large and possibly continually extended?

Presumably we need a completely different strategy to deal with it in a piecemeal fashion?

Would such an implementation look like constructing a buffer object that is periodically updated as the data is inbound, and then having sampling logic to deal with the "delta", process it and pass it on?

And that this would have to be done asynchronously to avoid blocking everything else on the event loop?

Is this essentially what Node.js streams are?

Comment: You're right, I'd suggest you read about *streams* in Javascript.

Comment: Do you know of a good reference?

Answer (score 1):

[...str] will convert string into array of 1-character strings, which will occupy additional memory. Then .filter() will produces another array of strings, which could be as big as previous one, depending on input data. End then, the resulting string.

If you concerned about possible memory and/or performance, you can implement this with regular cycle "for" and "charAt" function.

Comment: And use `Array#splice` for the removals?

Comment: @BenAston Splice is pretty slow on large arrays, it generally depends on how many elements need to be moved. But why would you use arrays, if you can avoid them altogether?

Comment: So, you would use a for-loop to enumerate the characters and construct a new string incrementally (using `String#concat`) without the unwanted chars?

Comment: @BenAston exactly

Comment: This will of course create approx (length of input * strings) when constructing the output...

Comment: @BenAston Just tried this code: `var s=new Array(100000000).join(" "); var st=new Date().getTime(); for(var i=0; i<1000000; i++) s+=".";console.log(new Date().getTime()-st); console.log(s.length);` - "+=" seem to be optimized and size of string does not matter